# Ambiguous constructor

Tags: c++, parameters, constructor

Well, I'm newbie to C++ and I was practicing with constructors. I'm creating a bad version of `String` class and I have been asked to do the next task:

a) Create a constructor where you can make a conversion from `const char*` to `String`.

b) Create a constructor with the 'n' first letters from a `const char*`. If 'n' is longer than this `const char*`, a copy of this `const char*` will be written as `String`. If 'n == 0', the program will write an empty `String`.

I think I had no problems implementing them; this is what I have:

```
Cadena::Cadena(const char* cad){

    tam_ = strlen(cad);
    s_ = new char[tam_ + 1];

    strcpy(s_,cad);
}

Cadena::Cadena(const char* cad, unsigned lon){

    tam_ = lon;
    s_ = new char[tam_ + 1];

    for(unsigned i = 0; i < tam_; i++){

        s_[i] = cad[i];
    }

    s_[tam_] = '\0';
}
```

My problem comes when I try to test them in my main method, where I get this error: "c1 is ambiguous".

I tried making this with a dummy parameter (declaring my `unsigned` parameter as an `int` with no name in my header) but I would like to initizialite this second parameter to 0 and I can't make this using a dummy parameter.

I know that the compiler doesn't know which constructor must use, but I would like to do this somehow. Can somebody help me? Sorry for my bad English.

Comment: Show the main method please.

Comment: why the for loop instead of just strcpy in the second constructor?

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. It sounds like you've got a default argument for the length parameter in the second constructor. If that's the case, of course it's ambiguous. How is the compiler to know whether you want to call the first constructor, or the second one with the second argument set to zero?

Comment: Your second constructor has a bug in it -- if `lon` is longer than `strlen(cad)`, it will try to read outside the bounds of `cad`.

Comment: @kfsone If he uses `strcpy` it will write outside the bounds if `lon > strlen(cad)`. He could use `strncpy` to solve that problem, though.

Comment: @barmar yes, I was thinking strncpy.

Answer (score 2):

> I'm creating a bad version of String class...

*NO NO NO*. This is never something you should do. You say you're a beginner to c++, that doesn't mean you will be writing "bad" code, maybe it's naive, long, has bad syntax, and is not the best solution but that doesn't make it "bad". Also, if you really think that your string class is "bad" than i suggest you redo it. You're in the process of learning, don't intentionally write code that you  *know* is below your standard. How you code now will influence how you write "better" code in the future even if you think it won't.

So please, for your benefit and for future people who will be working with your code, don't ever try and get away with "bad" code. Cheers!

Comment: Yes, I guess you're right. I will rewrite it and I will try to do it just using one constructor instead two of them. I think it's possible to do it somehow. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This is not an answer, it should just be a comment.

Answer (score -2):

Actually, you only need one constructor. Also, what you are doing in both function is basically the same, so you can call one from the other if you  really want two function. Instead of having two separate Cadena::Cadena(const char* cad) and Cadena::Cadena(const char* cad, unsigned lon), you can just use Cadena::Cadena(const char* cad, unsigned lon = 0), and you can just call Cadena tmp(c), and it will work.

So constructor is going to be

```
Cadena::Cadena(const char* cad, unsigned int lon = 0) {
    tam_ = (lon > 0 ? lon: strlen(cad));
    s_ = new char[tam_ + 1];

    strcpy(s_, cad);
    s_[tam_] = '\0';
}
```

and your main/tester can be called like this.

```
int main()
{
    char s[] = "Hello";
    Cadena c(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Your constructor doesn't use `lon` for anything. And how does it distinguish the constructor being called with 1 argument, which should copy the entire string, and being called with `n = 0`, which should create an empty string?

Comment: I agree with @Barmar.  Maybe `lon`'s default value should be -1, in which case, behave like the OP's first constructor, and if >= 0, behave like the OP's second constructor?

Comment: haha. I forgot, I was in rush. Now, I consider lon in the function.

Comment: I have  two questions. If lon = 0; it should be an empyty String. How does this code solve that? The other one is that if strcpy is used with a const char* which length is shorter than the one passed by parameter (it means, that his length depends of lon); would my program get an error because out_of_range?

Comment: @xFunkyTImes You will get undefined behavior, not necessarily an error, because there's no required bounds checking of C-style arrays.